# How do I loop through every directory in a given absolute path in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, path, filepath

I have a given absolute path such as: /hello/this/is/path/of/directories

My goal is to loop through this absolute path and print each directories name and display information about it in a separate line.

For example looping through the above absolute path would give:

ls-header        directory-name

ls information + / (the root)

ls information + hello

ls information + this

ls information + is

ls information + path

ls information + of

ls information + directories

I want to print the ls -d information for each directory in the path and the display the directory name at the end. Right now my code can obtain the absolute path but after that im not sure where to go. If this is too vague please let me know and I can try and specify. Thank you.

Comment: You can use find command with maxdepth 1. `find /your/path/here -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ls -ld "{}" \;`

Comment: @BarathVutukuri I think that is giving me too many directories. When I run it it gives me all the other directories in each of the parent directories. All I want is the ls information about the directories directly along the path. So for the above example it would only show 7 ls lines.

Comment: Doesn't simply `ls -ld /hello/this/is/path/of/directories/*` do what you want? Maybe throw in an `-a` and/or list the parent directory separately, like `/hello/this/is/path/of/directories{,/*}`

Answer (score 1):

One way splits your path into an array of its individual elements and then converts those into complete paths by prepending the previous element of the array to each element in turn, starting with the second:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

show_path() {
    local -a paths
    IFS=/ read -r -a paths <<<"$1"
    local i
    for (( i = 1; i < ${#paths[@]}; i++ )); do
        paths[i]="${paths[i-1]}/${paths[i]}"
    done
    paths[0]=/
    ls -d "${paths[@]}"
}


show_path /hello/this/is/path/of/directories
```

Comment: For some reason when I run that it only prints out the split up path names but not the actual ls information for each directory.

Comment: @SleepYet Are you perhaps wanting `ls -ld`, not just `ls -d` like you said in your question?

Comment: (`ls-d` seemed like an odd choice unless you just want the names, in which case there are better options...)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want these in order, I used a `sort`.

```
x=/hello/this/is/path/of/directories
ls -d $( while [[ -n "$x" ]]; do echo "$x"; x="${x%/*}"; done | sort )
```